# Find And Replace Files Or Folders By Name In SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have several websites on my hosting account. Due to the security layers in place I cannot use symbolic linking, or include from from account to account. However I am a set of scripts that are going to be the same account several accounts.

Rather than uploading these scripts to each individual ftp account every time a change is made I want to have a simple bash script that will do it for me.

So what I want to do via SSH is to search my hosting server for a specific directory by name, for example "ThisUniqueFolder", then upload and replace all the files within that directory with the updated versions of the files that are stored on my local server.

Keeping in mind that this directory "ThisUniqueFolder" will exist in several different locations throughout the hosting server.

Comment: So for example... find all directories called "ThisUniqueFolder" on hosting server and replace files in "ThisUniqueFolder" with updated files in "ThisUniqueFolder" on the local server.

Comment: You could use the proper tool, e.g. (`rsync -uav ThisUniqueFolder/ remote.server.tld:/path/to/ThisUniqueFolder`) **note the trailing** `'/'`, or you could omit the trailing `'/'` and use `rsync -uav ThisUniqueFolder remote.server.tld:/path/to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ssh` to find all `ThisuniqueFolder`, then use `rsync` to update them all.

Use `ssh`'s `-i identity_file` to avoid password for `user` at `remote_host`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `ssh -i /path/to/identity_file user@remote_host 'find /remote/search/directory -name "ThisUniqueFolder" -type d'`
do 
    rsync -avu -e 'ssh -i /path/to/identity_file' ThisUniqueFolder/ user@remote_host:$f
done
```